# For Kubernetes deployment in which file should I keep my environment variables, docker-compose.yml or *-deployment.yaml?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, dockerfile, environment-variables

For Kubernetes deployment in which file should I keep my environment variables, docker-compose.yml or *-deployment.yaml?

I read that we pass environment variables (like LOG_LEVEL=development npm run start) in the docker-compose file but I also saw the environment variable values assigned in *-deployment.yaml as well.

In docker-compose.yml I see environment variables under the 'environment' tag

```
environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
      LOG_LEVEL: debug
```

while in *-deployment.yaml I see the same environment variables under the 'env' tag like

```
env:
    - name: NODE_ENV
      value: 'production'
    - name: LOG_LEVEL
      value: 'info'
```

I want to know

1. Do I need to assign value to an environment variable in both files? and if not
2. In which file I should write my variables and which approach is better?

Comment: How kubernetes deployment is related to docker-compose.yml?

Comment: @Andromeda.. Sir, If I knew it perhaps I would have never come here. I am my self new to this "Kubernetes" thing

Comment: Sorry, I just wanted to know if I understood your question correctly. `docker-compose` is used with docker, and `deployment` is used in Kubernetes.

Answer (score 2):

Am not really sure what docker-compose.yaml has to do with Kubernetes, I think the `environment` of docker-compse` is to be used with docker-compose as a local setup, which is separated from Kubernetes which should be used with deployment

but you can use configMap with Kubernetes. A ConfigMap is an API object used to store non-confidential data in key-value pairs. Pods can consume ConfigMaps as environment variables, command-line arguments, or as configuration files in a volume

For example, `postgres-config.yaml` file for postgres configuration

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: postgres-config
  labels:
    app: postgres
data:
  POSTGRES_DB: postgresdb
  POSTGRES_USER: admin
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: psltest
```

Then you can apply the file like

```
kubectl apply -f postgres-config.yaml
```

And this can be used in all the *-deployment.yaml using `envFrom`

```
envFrom:
   - configMapRef:
      name: postgres-config
```

For more information about ConfigMap [Check here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/)

Comment: Yes, configmap is a valid solution. However, you can also define environment variables in kubernetes deployments.

Comment: of course you can, but through development process, Its easier to use configMap than to update code all the time, consider a scenario that you are running a local k8s for development on your machine and one for a cloud, instant of changing the IP from `localhost` to `cloud.ip` you can have two configMap one for local env and one for cloud env, which make things way easier.